# Amazon sns mobile push CreatePlatformEndpoint creates multiple endpoints with same token and user data

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I am using amazon sns mobile push for sending push notifications.For registering the device token with amazon I am using the CreatePlatformEndpoint.

As per amazon documentation(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_CreatePlatformEndpoint.html) :

The CreatePlatformEndpoint action is idempotent, so if the requester already owns an endpoint with the same device token and attributes, that endpoint's ARN is returned without creating a new endpoint.

But when I use the CreatePlatformEndpoint I am able to register the same token with the same attributes(User data) multiple times(upto 3 times). Not able to understand this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

chetna bhandari,

I was having this problem. I have a platform application for iOS (APNS) and another one for Android (GCM). For iOS, the method createPlatformEndpoint works fine. But for Android, creates multiples endpoints (up to 3, just like you) with same token. Next time I tried to use createPlatformEndpoint, throws an exception.

The correct way to do this is storing the endpoint in your application. If it's not stored yet, create and store.

Then, the pseudo-code is:

```
retrieve the latest device token from the mobile operating system
if (the platform endpoint ARN is not stored)
  # this is a first-time registration
  call create platform endpoint
  store the returned platform endpoint ARN
endif

call get endpoint attributes on the platform endpoint ARN 

if (while getting the attributes a not-found exception is thrown)
  # the platform endpoint was deleted 
  call create platform endpoint with the latest device token
  store the returned platform endpoint ARN
else 
  if (the device token in the endpoint does not match the latest one) or 
      (get endpoint attributes shows the endpoint as disabled)
    call set endpoint attributes to set the latest device token and then 
enable the platform endpoint
  endif
endif
```

You can see in this link: 
[Create a Platform Endpoint and Manage Device Tokens](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-platform-endpoint.html)